# Sheets Resize rows if value is found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I have the drop-down list that you can see in the image and I want to create a script that automatically resizes the activerow (the one with the drop-down list) but also the row below to size 20.

I also want to resize the other to rows below (row+3 and +4) to an other size.

I have this script written but I'm sure there is a lot of errors so feel free to do it from scratch

```
function HistoryTrigger(e) {

 var ss = e.range.getSheet();
 if (ss.getName() === 'Intervalo' && 'Refeição') {
   var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   a = getActiveRange()
   ss.getActiveSheet().setRowHeights(a, 2, 20);
var a = a + 2
   ss.getActiveSheet().setRowHeights(a, 2, 2);

   }
 }
```

THANKS A LOT, this is my first time uploading a question so I'm open also to suggestions on how to be more clear

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].  Consider taking a basic js course on functions, methods and return types.

Comment: Would you consider providing a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you're working on, and clearly indicate what outcome you expect? I assume you have installed an `onEdit` trigger?

Answer (score 0):

```
function HistoryTrigger(e) {
 var sh = e.range.getSheet();
 if (sh.getName()=='Intervalo && Refeição') { 
   sh.setRowHeight(e.range.rowStart,20);
 }
}
```